# Storing values without DB

Tags: php, jquery, html, database, localdb

I am developing a website using HTML5, js, php,... I have a doubt and I don't know if can be solved.

I have a settings tabs, where I select some alerts from values received from thingspeak. For example using a temperature sensor, I select from 10 to 20 ºC the alert and then depends on the value received it will be shown a notification. I have not developed this part yet, but I want to know if would be possible to save that. I have a DB for the user details, but I want to save this without saving this into a DB.

The main problem of this I think is when you close the web browser and the slider values will be restored when you open again. How can I save those alert settings? Should the best option to store in a db? How can I do this?, because can have more than 10 alerts, and I don't know how to store this in a db

Comment: Yes you should use them. Databases are used to store data that you want - why would you not want to use them?

Comment: sessions, cookies, flat file, but db would be best

Comment: you could try html5 storage....[w3Schools HTML Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) , Clearable by the user, as are cookies, DB is the best option,failing that then a simple text file on your server.

Comment: And which will be best option? To store in a database with different tables, for example one table for temperature alerts and store user Id, max min and active or store all the alerts for a user in a text file saved in the server? Is this an option? And then maybe could be retrieved as a json or similar...

Answer (score 0):

Cookies would do a pretty nice job especially if you can handle their dimensional form but you have to put in mind that if you personally want these data/information in the nearest/far future then you have no choice but to stick with the conventional DB.